# Array out of bounds by checking elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My for loop is always going out of bounds. It keeps checking whether the element is > 0. I tried plenty of restrictions, but none of them worked. Do you have any suggestions?

```
###Creation of the graph in a method
def graph(self):
    ###Creation of the given array I added zero rows and columns because of no restrictions at the boarders.
    a = np.array([
        [0, 16, 12, 21, 0, 0, 0],
        [16, 0, 0, 17, 20, 0, 0],
        [12, 0, 0, 28, 0, 31, 0],
        [21, 17, 28, 0, 18, 19, 23],
        [0, 20, 0, 18, 0, 0, 11],
        [0, 0, 31, 19, 0, 0, 27],
        [0, 0, 0, 23, 11, 27, 0]]),
        ###Determination of datatype size
        dtype = np.uint8
    )
    ###Graph dictionary for letting the bfs know who's connected to whom
    graph = {}
    ###For loop in order to iterate through the elements
    for r in range(len(a)):
        for c in range(len(a)):
            ###Checking whether element is greater than 0
            if a[r, c] > 0:
                ###List of coordinates for checking elements connection
                d = [r-1, c+1, r+1, c-1]
                ###Checking whether one of the surrounding elements is greater than 0
                if (a[d[0], c] > 0 and r >= 0) or (a[r, d[1]] > 0 and c <= len(a)) or (a[d[2], c] > 0 and r <= len(a)) or (a[r, d[3]] > 0 and c >= 0):
                    ###Creates the key in the dictionary without values
                    graph[a[r, c]] = []
                    ###Add value(s) to the specific key in the dictionary
                    if a[d[0], c] > 0:
                        graph[a[r, c]].append(a[d[0], c])
                    if a[r, d[1]] > 0:
                        graph[a[r, c]].append(a[r, d[1]])
                    if a[d[2], c] > 0:
                        graph[a[r, c]].append(a[d[2], c])
                    if a[r, d[3]] > 0:
                        graph[a[r, c]].append(a[r, d[3]])
    ###Return of the graph in form of a dictionary
    return(graph)
```

Comment: You must also check that it doesn't go over `len(a)-2`, as you produce the indices `r+1` and `c+1` in `d` as well.

Comment: im getting a syntax error when i try to interpret your code in idle `[0, 0, 0, 23, 11, 27, 0]),` extra parentheses

Comment: your out of bounds is because of the values in the `d` list. Items in there take values up to `len(a)` and down to `-1` - both of those result in error in the following if statement. For example,  check the value of `d[0]` and `d[3]` during the first iteration when your `r` and `c` both have `0` as value

Comment: What is the overall intent of the algorithm? Also: did you consider padding the array on each side with dummy values that give the correct result, and then skipping those in the iteration?

Comment: Also, since we're already using Numpy, I'm sure these comparisons can be done much more elegantly.

Comment: It's going out of bounds because of the "checking whether one of the surrounding...". It has nothing to do with len(function).
I need a restriction which takes care of that problem. I tried and function but it doesn't work

Comment: First, as @Karl pointed out, you need to decide what will you do with the outer points. Will you ignore those surroundings or will you insert "imaginary" outer neighbours. The rest of our suggestions will depend on that.

Comment: I did padding and it worked but I don't intend to add padding. There must be a way to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of why the restrictions don't work, let's examine one of them for example (substituing in the `d[0]` value, since the `d` list isn't actually helping us either with solving the problem or simplifying the code):

```
a[r-1, c] > 0 and r >= 0
```

The short-circuiting behaviour of `and` can be used to make sure that a value isn't checked, yes. But the short-circuiting works the other way around. In this example, `a[d[0], c] > 0` is tested unconditionally, and then `r >= 0` is only tried if the first thing resulted in a truthy value. But the first part causes an error, so the second is too late to prevent the error. You wanted `r >= 0 and a[r-1, c] > 0`. (By substituting in `r-1` for `d[0]`, it becomes clearer: we check the value of `r`, and *then* try the indexing that uses `r`.)

---

But we can do much better than this by taking advantage of Numpy operations. Numpy is pretty much specifically designed to make these kinds of problems both simpler to code and more performant.

The first thing we want to do is see the places where there is a non-zero value in the data:

```
>>> a = np.array([
...     [0, 16, 12, 21, 0, 0, 0],
...     [16, 0, 0, 17, 20, 0, 0],
...     [12, 0, 0, 28, 0, 31, 0],
...     [21, 17, 28, 0, 18, 19, 23],
...     [0, 20, 0, 18, 0, 0, 11],
...     [0, 0, 31, 19, 0, 0, 27],
...     [0, 0, 0, 23, 11, 27, 0]
... ], dtype = np.uint8)
>>> a
array([[ 0, 16, 12, 21,  0,  0,  0],
       [16,  0,  0, 17, 20,  0,  0],
       [12,  0,  0, 28,  0, 31,  0],
       [21, 17, 28,  0, 18, 19, 23],
       [ 0, 20,  0, 18,  0,  0, 11],
       [ 0,  0, 31, 19,  0,  0, 27],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 23, 11, 27,  0]], dtype=uint8)
>>> a != 0 # Yes, it's really *this* easy
array([[False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False]])
```

And let's get the indices of those positions:

```
>>> np.where(a != 0)
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6,
       6, 6], dtype=int64), array([1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 4, 0, 3, 5, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 6, 2, 3, 6, 3,
       4, 5], dtype=int64))
```

This result is a bit hard to make sense of; we get a tuple of two 1-d arrays, representing all the x-coords and y-coords of the non-zero values (They're also stored using your system's native integer type, since they're indices; as you can see, I'm on a 64-bit machine). Fortunately, it's also easy to make Numpy pair them up:

```
>>> np.transpose(np.where(a != 0))
# long output omitted
```

That's all well and good, but now how do we look for neighbours? I'll consider the case of neighbours above the current position, and leave the rest as an exercise.

The way we'll do this is to build an array whose values represent the one above the original array position (filling in zeros for the top row). We do that by slicing the array, and then adding a row. The rows we want are all except for the *last*, and then we fill in zeros across the *top*. But an easier way to do that is to start with an equal-sized 2d array of zeros, and put the relevant rows into the *bottom*. So:

```
>>> above = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
>>> above[1:, :] = a[:-1, :]
>>> above
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 16, 12, 21,  0,  0,  0],
       [16,  0,  0, 17, 20,  0,  0],
       [12,  0,  0, 28,  0, 31,  0],
       [21, 17, 28,  0, 18, 19, 23],
       [ 0, 20,  0, 18,  0,  0, 11],
       [ 0,  0, 31, 19,  0,  0, 27]], dtype=uint8)
```

Notice the pairs of values used for slicing: each corresponds to a separate dimension of the array. So `[1:, :]` slices from the row 1 onwards, keeping all columns, as the destination; `[:-1, :]` slices every row except the last, as our source data.

Now we can check for places that are non-zero and also have a non-zero neighbour above:

```
>>> (a != 0) & (above != 0)
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False]])
```

(The parentheses are necessary here; explaining is a bit difficult.)

Finally we can look at *those* coordinates, and for each of them, record a graph link in the normal way:

```
>>> for r, c in np.transpose(np.where((a != 0) & (above != 0))):
...    print('there is a link from ({r}, {c}) to ({r - 1}, {c})')
```